# Flask - Getting request parameters in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, curl, flask, httprequest

I'm running Flask on App Engine and I'm having trouble getting the request parameters of an issued request.

Here's my function being called:

```
@APP.route('/some_model/new', methods = ['PUT'])
def new_some_model():
    prop1 = request.args.get('prop1')
    prop2 = request.args.get('prop2')
    import logging
    logging.error(prop1)
    logging.error(prop2)
```

And then I'm running the following command with curl:

```
curl -X PUT -d "prop1=prop1&prop2=prop2" http://myapp.appspot.com/some_function/new
```

I've tried several variations, but with no success. The curl command returns a "500 server error" and in the app-log I see that both prop1 and prop2 are `None` at the point of logging. The server error came from the properties being required later on. So the problem is that the request.args.get() is returning nothing. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Thank you much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data sent by `POST` or `PUT` will be in [`request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.form), [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args) is for parsed query string data.